# Converting CF Session variables to a date format

Tags: date, coldfusion

Is it possible to convert ColdFusion session variables into a date format as such MM/DD/YYYY?

Right now what was created were three drop downs Month, Day, Year:
Ex. Aug 5 1986

The user wants these drop downs instead of just having one date picker. But then on the form they want that date in the format as of MM/DD/YYYY.

I have it showing as `#session.checkout.info.birthmonth_1# #session.checkout.info.birthday_1# #session.checkout.info.birthyear_1#`

Is it some how possible to convert those three variables into that date format?

Comment: Take it one variable at a time.  Start with the year, it's the easiest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the `CreateDate(year, month, day)` function

Or in your case

```
 session.checkout.info.birthdate = CreateDate(
          session.checkout.info.birthyear_1, 
          session.checkout.info.birthmonth_1, 
          session.checkout.info.birthday_1);
```

The you can use a date formatting function to display as needed

```
 #session.checkout.info.birthdate.LSDateFormat()#
```

Source: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/CreateDate.html

Comment: Does that function not require 3 numbers?

Comment: I think you are right, the month appears to be a string. I wonder if something can be done to unstringify it. Or maybe try using `parsedatetime()`

Comment: I am going to keep the question up since you provided good information. You opened my eyes though I could just change the values on the selects to be those numbers and keep the session variables just putting a / inbetween them. Or do you not recommend that method?

Comment: You should write up an answer for the solution that worked. That way others can see how this can be solved.

Comment: @David Brierton - I think what he is recommending is creating and storing a *single* date. Those can be easily reformatted however you need. IMO, that's a lot simpler than carrying around three separate values that are a mix of strings and numbers.  Since the values are from drop down lists, you can easily change the list *values* to be numbers, but still display something different.

Comment: As `<input type="date">` become more common, it once again is easier to deal with dates as a single variable.

Comment: @DavidBrierton, you can't simply put slashes between the variables.  First, your Month is not a number.  Second, your desired format calls for leading zeros.

Comment: @DanBracuk They were three selects. I just changed the values. So for months instead of the abreviation like Aug the new value became 08,same with days just add the leading 0s for the single digits in the value. Add the slashes and voila. I do like how he converts it into one variable which is something I would have never thought of. That is why his answer was chosen for the correct answer.

Comment: Hope you didn't create a `fix A break B` situation when you changed the values of those selects.  It happens to me a lot.